How to apply Google IAM policy to all users without going through the users one by one?
For example, I want all the project members to have an expiry of 90 days for a specific project. There's a condition builder for every account but is there a way that I can set this policy to all members at once?


Create a Google group or several. Add the users to the group(s). Then you can apply IAM policies to the group. AFAIK, none of the Google commands will apply IAM changes to a list of users. Writing a script would not be hard.
